# zsh: command not found: ls на MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, flutter, zsh

Пытался добавить `export PATH="$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin` с помощью vim 
`vim ~/.zshrc` но что то пошло не так. Теперь не работают почти все команд, а `echo $PATH` выдает 
`/Users/andrej/Developer/flutter/bin`

Answer (score 1):

1. `vim (или nano) ~/.zshrc`
2. `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin"`
3. `echo $PATH`
4. `which flutter`